# Unidac / MyDac / SQL - I have problem with fast insert about 1000 rows

Tags: mysql, delphi, unidac, mydac

I use unidac components. And i have problem with fast insert about 1000 rows.

```
var
  query: TUniquery;
begin
  query.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Table (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (:b0,:b1,:b2);');
  for I := 0 to 1000 do
  begin
   Query.ParamByName('b0').AsInteger := 1;  
   Query.ParamByName('b1').AsInteger := 2;
   Query.ParamByName('b2').AsInteger := Random(100);
   Query.Prepare;
   Query.Execute;  //1000 times is very slow
end;
```

It is faster

```
var
  query: TUniquery;
begin
  for I := 0 to 1000 do
    Query.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Table (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (1,2,Random(100));');
  end;
  Query.Execute;  //1 times - is fast add 
end;
```

But, I would like to use the first format with the procedure  **Query.ParamByName('b1').AsInteger := 2;** because it is clearer and with a large number of columns I find myself easier to find.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Maybe you have some other ways to quickly insert a large number of rows with different data?

Comment: `prepare()` should be called only once. See also [here](https://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/batchops.htm) for an efficient way of doing a large number of inserts.

Comment: I use MySQL, I don't always use transactions, sometimes it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Olivier thank you for the link, there is Batch Operations and it is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to quickly insert a large number of records, you should use batch updates. You can read more about batch inserting into MySQL using UniDAC (or MyDAC) in their [blog](https://blog.devart.com/using-batch-operations-in-delphi-data-access-components.html)